# How to set ANDROID_HOME path in Ubuntu

Tags: android

I am working with Appium (beginner). I have to connect the device connected using USB with Appium. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

My questions are how to find and set ANDROID_HOME path.

Answer (score 6):

Before anything download the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html), `unzip` that file into your home folder then open your `$HOME/.bashrc` file and add the following lines to locate that folder and set your ANDROID_HOME:

```
nano $HOME/.bashrc
```

Now add these lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Now close the current terminal and open a new one. Run `echo $ANDROID_HOME` and you should see that added path.

**Again, make sure you download the one for Linux, not the Windows version**.

Comment: This only works for the current terminal session.

Comment: @shahidkarimi how so?

Comment: @Shahid Karimi, do "source $HOME/.bashrc" to apply it across the board.